# Cordova Issue "Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'."

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, onesignal, cordova-3

I am getting below issue during "cordova build":
My Android version:8.1.0
Cordova Version:Latest
Gradle Version:4.2
Getting it due to onesignal plugin but it gone when I remove plugin

```
?? actionable tasks: ? executed, ?? up-to-date
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource compilation failed
  C:\Users\AJ\Desktop\blogapp\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v२३\values-v२३.xml: error: invalid configuration 'v२३'.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Comment: Same issue here, when I'm trying to install a new package within Meteor (which includes Cordova). @ajay-malik could you add the meteor tag too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I abled to fix the issue my reinstalling cordova and android studio, This issue occur because of wrongly configured SDKs